# Adding a tilde between two tilde characters if the character count between the two tilde is greater then 60

Tags: javascript, function

I have a string of text that I would like to split via tilde (~) every 60 characters in javascript.

I have;

UXXXXXXquXXX pXXXtXXXXXXXXXt ID: ~XXXTEST COPYXXX~XXXGXXXstrosXXXopy RXXXportXXX~NXXXXXXXXX: XXXDELTAXXX,DXXXXXXsy~CXXXsXXX XXXotXXX XXXo: XXX999999999XXX~45678: XXXXXX~DXXXtXXX oXXX XXXXXXrtXXX: XXX18\12\1968XXX~AXXXXXXrXXXss: TXXXXXX NXXXw StrXXXXXXt, TXXXXXX ArXXXXXX, CXXXXXXstXXXr, . CZZZL~ZZ: TEST, TXXXXXX GrXXXXXXt SuttoXXX MXXXXXX.Ctr. (XXXXXXuXXX), TXXXXXX GrXXXXXXt SuttoXXX MXXXXXX.Ctr., OXXXXXX CXXXXXXstXXXr RoXXXXXX, GrXXXXXXt SuttoXXX, EXXXXXXXXXsXXXXXXrXXX Port, ZZZ ZPB~XXXProXXXXXXXXXurXXX XXXXXXtXXX:XXX 29\03\2016~XXXStXXXtus:XXX ~XXXWXXXrXXX:XXX (XXXoXXXXXX)~XXXBUILDINGXXXtXXXXXX:XXX CouXXXtXXXss oXXX CXXXXXXstXXXr~XXXRXXXXXXXXXrrXXXXXXXXX XXXoXXXsuXXXtXXXXXXt:XXX ZZ
 (GPwer)~XXXCoXXXsuXXXtXXXXXXt\EXXXXXXosXXXopXXXst:XXX LXXXst XXXoXXXsuXXXtXXXXXXt:XXX EXXXXXXosXXXopXXXst No1: Mr ZZZ vXXXXXXs HelloXXXs: NXXXXXXoXXXXXX AsXXX StXXXXXXXXXXXX BXXXzXXXXXXt~XXXIXXXstruXXXXXXXXXt:XXX 11 GIF1T240 2130131~XXXPrXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtXXXoXXX:XXX ~XXXIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtXXXoXXXs:XXX ~XXXRXXXport:XXX TXXXXXX proXXXXXXXXXurXXX wXXXs XXXoXXXpXXXXXXtXXXXXX suXXXXXXXXXssXXXuXXXXXXy to D2.
~XXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXosXXXs:XXX ~XXXTXXXXXXrXXXpXXXutXXXXXX proXXXXXXXXXurXXXs:XXX ~XXXSpXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXs TXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXX ~XXXMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtion:XXX ~XXXFollow up:XXX ~XXXAdvice\comments:XXX ~

The string has a number of tilde aready and this is fine, happy to leave these as they are.  But in some instances if the number of characters between the tilde's is greater then 60, I would like to split that section (tilde to tilde) by adding another tilde at the 60'th Character point. and begin again, to the next tilde.

Basically between each tilde there should be no more then 60 characters, any less then this is fine.

Have tried numerous functions, last being.

```
function addtilde(str) {
  var result = '';
  while (str.length > 0) {
    result += str.substring(0, 60) + "~";
    str = str.substring(60);
  }
  return result;
}
```

No joy, any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace` on that string. It's a one-liner that looks for "no tilde, up to as much as 60 times, *optionally* followed by a tilde" and returns the not-tilde part plus a tilde.

```
str = str.replace ("([^\~]{1,60})\~?",
    function (fullmatch, partmatch) { return partmatch+'~'; }, "g");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun little recursive solution. In makes use of the handy `.indexOf` method on strings, which takes a second parameter that indicates the starting index for the string search.

Haven't tested, but it should work nicely. :)

```
function splitItUp(string, start) {
   if (start > string.length - 60) return string;
   var indexOf = string.indexOf('~', start);
   if (indexOf - start > 60 || indexOf === -1) {
      // insert the character
      string = string.substring(0, start + 60) + '~' + string.substring(start+60);
   }
   return splitItUp(string, start+60);
}
```

Kick off the recursion with a call

```
var res = splitItUp("my string", 0);
```

And it returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

Quite fun to do recursively (with ES6 syntax for conciseness):

```
var splitRun = txt => txt.length <= 60 
                       ? txt 
                       : (txt.substring(0,60) + "~" + splitRun(txt.substring(60)));
var runs = originalText.split("~");
var treatedText = runs.map(splitRun).join("~");
```

Otherwise, you can restate `splitRun` in ES5 syntax as follows:

```
var splitRun = function(txt){
    return txt.length <= 60 
            ? txt 
            : (txt.substring(0,60) + "~" + splitRun(txt.substring(60)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match a regex where it matches any number of characters from 1 to n, in this case 60. Then rejoin it with the same token.

```
str = "UXXXXXXquXXX pXXXtXXXXXXXXXt ID: ~XXXTEST COPYXXX~XXXGXXXstrosXXXopy RXXXportXXX~NXXXXXXXXX: XXXDELTAXXX,DXXXXXXsy~CXXXsXXX XXXotXXX XXXo: XXX999999999XXX~45678: XXXXXX~DXXXtXXX oXXX XXXXXXrtXXX: XXX18\12\1968XXX~AXXXXXXrXXXss: TXXXXXX NXXXw StrXXXXXXt, TXXXXXX ArXXXXXX, CXXXXXXstXXXr, . CZZZL~ZZ: TEST, TXXXXXX GrXXXXXXt SuttoXXX MXXXXXX.Ctr. (XXXXXXuXXX), TXXXXXX GrXXXXXXt SuttoXXX MXXXXXX.Ctr., OXXXXXX CXXXXXXstXXXr RoXXXXXX, GrXXXXXXt SuttoXXX, EXXXXXXXXXsXXXXXXrXXX Port, ZZZ ZPB~XXXProXXXXXXXXXurXXX XXXXXXtXXX:XXX 29\03\2016~XXXStXXXtus:XXX ~XXXWXXXrXXX:XXX (XXXoXXXXXX)~XXXBUILDINGXXXtXXXXXX:XXX CouXXXtXXXss oXXX CXXXXXXstXXXr~XXXRXXXXXXXXXrrXXXXXXXXX XXXoXXXsuXXXtXXXXXXt:XXX ZZ (GPwer)~XXXCoXXXsuXXXtXXXXXXt\EXXXXXXosXXXopXXXst:XXX LXXXst XXXoXXXsuXXXtXXXXXXt:XXX EXXXXXXosXXXopXXXst No1: Mr ZZZ vXXXXXXs HelloXXXs: NXXXXXXoXXXXXX AsXXX StXXXXXXXXXXXX BXXXzXXXXXXt~XXXIXXXstruXXXXXXXXXt:XXX 11 GIF1T240 2130131~XXXPrXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtXXXoXXX:XXX ~XXXIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtXXXoXXXs:XXX ~XXXRXXXport:XXX TXXXXXX proXXXXXXXXXurXXX wXXXs XXXoXXXpXXXXXXtXXXXXX suXXXXXXXXXssXXXuXXXXXXy to D2. ~XXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXosXXXs:XXX ~XXXTXXXXXXrXXXpXXXutXXXXXX proXXXXXXXXXurXXXs:XXX ~XXXSpXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXs TXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXX ~XXXMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtion:XXX ~XXXFollow up:XXX ~XXXAdvice\comments:XXX ~"
console.log(str.match(/[^~]{1,60}/g).join('~'));
```